# How to specify background image height in div Container

Tags: html, css

I have a container and i have two sections that i want to display one at a time. something like a scrolling webpage like [This](http://hackcampus.io)!

Basically how do i make the first div element (section) have its own background that fits to screen and the second section should have just a blank screen. Thank you very much ! please examples will be gladly appreciated :)

This is my css:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    /* look this up */
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

/* style what the sections have in common */
.container {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1em;

}


.about {

float:left;
height:auto;
width:100%;

background: url(10.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size:100%;




}

/* target specific sections */
.heads {
    background-color: red;
     float:left;
height:auto;
width:100%;
}
```

This is my Html:

```
<body>

<section class="container about">
    About
</section>

<section class="container heads">
    About
</section>

</body>
```

Comment: Try with "background-size:100% 600px;"  => 100% is the width and 600px the height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.container{
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1em;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size:100%;
}

.about{
    background: url(10.jpg);
}

.heads{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set your body and HTML height to 100%:

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Then change your `.about` to:

```
.about {

float:left;
height:100%;
width:100%;

...}
```

NOTE: If this is what you were looking for please remember to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

add this in your `.about` class

```
background-size:100% 500px;
```